# ¿Cómo detener al momento de refrescar una página?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

¿Cómo hacer un script para cuando un usuario recargue una página le muestre un alert para que confirme si realmente quiere recargar la página?.

He buscado y solo he encontrado de refrescar una página por determinado tiempo.

Comment: si alguna respuesta te ayudó, por favor, márcala como aceptada. Y te rogaría que hicieras lo mismo en todas las preguntas que haces en esta comunidad. Aunque no lo parezca, el ratio de respuestas hechas/respondidas es importante y nos ayudará a mejorar

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, puedes utilizar el evento "onbeforeunload" del elemento window en javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "¿Desea recargar la página web?";
};
```

Esto mostrará un prompt al usuario para que confirme que desea refrescar la página web.

Comment: Usé tu código js. Pero cuando le doy clic a botón submit me sale  prompt, ¿habría una manera de que no saliera?

Comment: Buenas, supongo que podrías meter el código:


  `window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "¿Desea recargar la página web?";
};`   Al principio del codigo para asi capturar los eventos generados por el usuario al intentar salir de la pagina. Y cuando quieras hacer el submit, puedes (antes de hacerlo), desactivar este manejo de eventos con el siguiente código:  

`window.onbeforeunload = null;`

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tienes un script para bloquear el boton **F5** y el boton **Recargar**

```
<script>
 document.onkeydown = function(e){
 tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
 alert(tecla)
 if (tecla == 116){
   if (confirm("Seguro que quieres refrescar la página ") == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
   }
 }
}
</script>>
```

Para el botón de **ATRÁS**

```
function NoBack(){
history.go(1)
}
```

Faltaría añadir la llamada a la función en el body.

```
<body OnLoad="NoBack();">
```

Espero que te sirva !

Comment: Amigo, estoy probando tú código y cada vez que tecleo algo me dice que si deseo recargar la página ¿Por qué?

Comment: @LittaHervi Tu intención es muy buena, pero no deberías editar el código de otra respuesta, sino publicar tu propia respuesta, aclarando (y referenciando) si te basaste en el código de otra persona

Answer (score 1):

Usa `confirm()` en vez de `alert()`
ya que `alert()` te dará sólo una opción de respuesta (**OK**) entonces si lo que quieres es que el usuario haga algo antes de actualizar lo hará igualmente...

`confirm()` obtiene un *true* si el usuario pulsa `OK` o *false* si pulsa `Cancelar`

```
if(confirm('Successful Message')){
    window.location.reload();  
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta explica un poco más. +1

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto, creo que e tenido el mismo problema que comentas, en mi caso tengo un form en el cual si el usuario modifica un campo de texto y se dirige a otra sección de la pagina sin dar submit. le sale un alert avisando.

```js
var formHasChanged = false;
var submitted = false;
$('form[name="mainform"] input, form[name="mainform"] select, form[name="mainform"] textarea').on('change',function (e) {
 formHasChanged = true;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  if (formHasChanged && !submitted) {
   var message = "You have not saved your changes.", e = e || window.event;
   if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
   }
   return message;
  }
 }
 $("form").submit(function() {
  submitted = true;
 });
});
```