# ¿Mostrar una alerta antes de la accion refresh?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Lo que busco es lo siguiente:
En el momento en que se dispare la accion para refrescar la pagina, me aparezca antes un mensaje como este:

```
swal({
                    title: "Se perderan los datos",
                    text: "¿Desea refrescar la pagina?"
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,              
                    confirmButtonText: "refrescar",
                    cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    closeOnCancel: true,

                }, function () {

                        //Cualquier cosa
                });
```

Pero desconozco el evento y su uso. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira esta pregunta: [¿Cómo detener al momento de refrescar una página?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57080/250)

Comment: @Necroyeti, ¿estas utilizando SweetAlert?

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev Asi es.

Answer (score 1):

No hay un evento que sea tan específico (saber que la acción que se va a ejecutar es "actualizar"), pero existe el evento `beforeunload` [(ver documentación aquí)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) que permite pedir la confirmación del usuario cuando va a dejar la página (ya sea para recargarla o para ir a otra dirección, eso es algo que no podemos saber por razones de seguridad). No todos los navegadores se comportan exactamente igual, pero tu función debe devolver un string que será mostrado (o no, según la política de cada navegador) en una ventana de confirmación al usuario.

Así que no podrás usar tu propia "ventana de confirmación", ni un `alert` ni un `confirm`, será el navegador el que elija qué mostrar.

Comment: ¿En ese caso no podria usar SweetAlert? ¿Tendria entonces que usar algo como el  `confirm()` en el `beforeunload()`?

Comment: Ni siquiera eso, actualizo la respuesta